# How to set DateTimeField input_formats without losing date/time picker widget in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I've been searching for an efficient way on how to achieve one seemingly simple task in Django by setting the DateTimeField's input_formats property.

Currently, the default DateTimeFormat is Y-m-d for the date, and the time has trailing seconds. I would like to change this around to m-d-Y and I:M respectively, but any kind of edit to the form removes the date and time picker widgets.

For example, when I do something like this in admin.py:

```
class PromoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    start_time = DateTimeField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
```

The resulting form in admin looks like (date/time picker widget disappears):
[image]

models.py:

```
class Promo(models.Model):
    start_time      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    end_time        = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

Is there a straightforward way to make this work? Gracias.